# How to display Woocommerce Checkout Notices Inline?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the checkout notices in Woocommerce inline, that is below or above their corresponding fields. I have tried this code:

```
/**
 * @snippet       Add Inline Field Error Notifications @ WooCommerce Checkout
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=86570
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.5.1
 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'bbloomer_checkout_fields_in_label_error', 10, 4 );

function bbloomer_checkout_fields_in_label_error( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if ( strpos( $field, '</label>' ) !== false && $args['required'] ) {
        $error = '<span class="error" style="display:none">';
        $error .= sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), $args['label'] );
        $error .= '</span>';
        $field = substr_replace( $field, $error, strpos( $field, '</label>' ), 0);
    }
    return $field;
}
```

and the CSS that comes with it:

```css
.woocommerce-checkout p.woocommerce-invalid-required-field span.error {
    color: #e2401c;
    display: block !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

but it does not work, as there is no field named `woocommerce-invalid-required-field` anywhere in my page source code. The location of the error messages, is in a totally different place at `.woocommerce-notices-wrapper .woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout ul`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This code works as `woocommerce-invalid-required-field` css class is added dynamically if you add something to a field and you remove it… But the code is not really good.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec for your answer, unfortunately this does not work for me. On any themes that I have tried, the error/validation messages are always shown at the top of the page (as is the default woo case).
Do you have a different code that works or a solution for this?